# Java, calling runnable task from another class

Tags: java, concurrency, runnable

I am trying to make a small program to interact with my Lifx bulbs.
I have a class Bulb, where i have made a runnable:

```
public Runnable runnableToggle = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            String url = "https://api.lifx.com/v1/lights/" + Bulb.this.ID + "/toggle/";

            URL obj = null;
            try {
                obj = new URL(url);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                System.out.println("Malformed URL");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            assert obj != null;
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

            String authS = "Bearer MY_TOKEN";
            con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authS);
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setDoOutput(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

However, when I call this form my main class, it does not work.

```
Thread t = new Thread(deskBulb.runnableToggle);
t.start();
```

The program just executes, and prints no errors.

If I run the exact same code as a "normal" function in the class, it works.

I haven't used runnables before, so probably a stupid mistake. In any case, thanks for the help to anyone who answers.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on `The program just executes, and prints no errors.`?

Comment: yes, it executes once - what did you expect?

Comment: Have you tried debug, to see if code will be executed? Or lets put "log debug" to show what the code do.

Comment: And, what is the variable "deskBulb"?

Comment: @user7 The program builds, executes, and shuts down, without any exceptions.

Comment: @BrunoCarletti I tried running with debug, and it goes through all the lines of code. My bulb does not change state though. deskBulb is an instance of Bulb.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I expected my light bulb to turn on lol.

Comment: Well, If Your code called the "POST" method, what is your http return? Http 200/201? I think that problem occur in REST service that you calling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code running without errors, the problem probably come of the service REST, try add response code return to see more about the return:

```
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();

//print result
System.out.println(response.toString());
```

Comment: Apparently, I need to call getResponseCode(), and then the bulb turns on/off as expected.
That's weird.
But anyway, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your class `Bulb` should implement a `Runnable` interface, then implement run method like  that :

```
public class Bulb implements Runnable{
...
  @Override
  public void run() {
  // add your logic here
  }
...
}
```

Then, create an instance of you class, and start the `thread` :

```
Bulb bulb = new Bulb();
Thread t = new Thread(bulb );
t.start();
```

Comment: Does this make any difference? Can you explain more?

Comment: the class shouldn't necessarily be `Runnable`, it can just contain a `Runnable` task. I don't see how your answer might be useful

Comment: I tried that. Same result.
Also, as Andrew said, it should not make any difference.

Comment: Implement a `Runnable` interface is more clean than having a `Runnable` task, it wasn't clear if `runnableToggle` was instanciated correctly or not.